# I'd like to set all the values in a boolean array to false without re-initializing it

Tags: java, arrays, boolean

```
    public boolean used[] = new boolean[26];
```

Here is what I have, and it's working great. I know they are all going to be set as false by default. But, as my application is used for a while, some of those are changed to "true". (Which is fine, since that's what my code is supposed to do).

I'm trying to create a "reset" button, which will simulate a reset-like action. Where all variables are restored to what they were when the window was initially created (all drawings go away - just a fresh restart).

And I need all of those true booleans to go back to false in one fell swoop. Any ideas?

Answer (score 22):

Use [`Arrays.fill`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill%28boolean%5B%5D,%20boolean%29):

```
Arrays.fill(used, false);
```

Answer (score 3):

*Arrays.fill* uses a *rangecheck* before filling your array.

```
public static void fill(Object[] a, int fromIndex, int toIndex, Object val) {
        rangeCheck(a.length, fromIndex, toIndex);
        for (int i=fromIndex; i<toIndex; i++)
            a[i] = val;
    }

/**
     * Check that fromIndex and toIndex are in range, and throw an
     * appropriate exception if they aren't.
     */
    private static void rangeCheck(int arrayLen, int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
        if (fromIndex > toIndex)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("fromIndex(" + fromIndex +
                       ") > toIndex(" + toIndex+")");
        if (fromIndex < 0)
            throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException(fromIndex);
        if (toIndex > arrayLen)
            throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException(toIndex);
    }
```

if you don't need rangeCheck, you can just use a *forloop* to fill up your boolean array.

```
for(int i = 0; i < used.length; ++i){
    used[i] = false;
}
```

Comment: Where does this source come from? Do we need to attribute it/link?

Comment: @Chris: It is the java source, I use maven and we can say download sources and javadoc along with binaries. Just followed what Arrays.fill does ( F3 shortcut ) and the code is there. I copied and pasted it from there. or you can go to jarvana and search for it.

Comment: Does the license of your source allow it to be pasted here without attribution?

Comment: @Chris Java is an open source, you can view their code online and use it for non-commercial distribution.

Comment: @Chris
Sun also makes the JDK source code available for researchers and others interested in exploring the details of the JDK. Over the past several years, Sun has made the source code available via the Sun Community Source License (SCSL) terms. Sun continues to use SCSL for JDK 5.0. In addition, Sun is also releasing JDK 5.0 under the new Java Research License (JRL) which simplifies access to JDK 5.0 source code. Researchers and universities should find the JRL much easier to understand and work with compared to SCSL.
Source: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/source_license.html

Answer (score 2):

You can just recreate your array, it will be initialized by default to false.

That is when you implement the reset yo can do

```
used[] = new boolean[26];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `java.util.Arrays.fill()`:

```
Arrays.fill(used, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    boolean a[]= new boolean[nums.length];

    Arrays.fill(a, false);
```

// this will help you fill array of boolean with false.

// remember to -> import java.util.Arrays;